# Windows Phone 8 Ntlm\Kerberos authentication?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, kerberos, ntlm

Is it possible to authenticate with a server that uses Ntlm\Kerberos authentication from a Windows Phone 8 app ?
is there any workaround for this, even If I will have to send some hard coded tokens in the headers ?

Comment: Yes. Internet Explorer mobile supports Windows Authentication and there's a internet explorer control you can use when developing your app. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm developing a native Windows Phone 8 application, I'm not using the browser control

Comment: And I'm saying that I think the easiest way to perform said authentication from a native app is with the browser control - it doesn't have to be visible.

Comment: Would you please explain more, how can I authenticate with the browser while it's invisible ?